# How to get csv delimiter for current locale?

Tags: python, csv, locale, delimiter

I have script that could be run on PC with English or Russian locale. 
The script writes some data to csv file:

```python
with open(FILE_NAME, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=CSV_DELIMITER)
    writer.writeheader()
```

The problem is that delimiter in English locale is comma (,) and in Russian locale, it is semicolon (;).
For now I' ve solved it by analyzing locale ('en' or 'ru') and sending delimiter specific for current locale to code that writes data to csv file:

```python
def get_csv_delimiter():
    default_locale = locale.getdefaultlocale()
    language_code = default_locale[0][0:2]
    if language_code in ['en']:
        delimiter = ','
    elif language_code in ['ru']:
        delimiter = ';'
    return delimiter
```

But if I need to add other locales I add new if's or dictionary kind of `{locale: locale_delimeter}` to `get_csv_delimiter` function.
Is there any simplier way to get delimiter for current locale?

Comment: note: `if language_code in ['en']` => `if language_code == 'en'`

Comment: For your use-case, using a dictionary would be appropriate. Have you tried and facing any difficulty?

Comment: I think you are talking different worlds for locale and csv dialect. Determining a locale does not guarantee a delimiter for you in any way. The program or the user who produced a CSV could have used any delimiter on any locale.